# Weekly sum divide by number of days and visualize on a bar chart

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lscT.png)
This is a very simplified version of my table. I want to add up the orders for the whole week, divide it by the number of days and visualize it on the bar chart. So, for each date, the value will look like this. For 11 to 15 sept week, the total 510 divided by 5days is 84. All the days are weekdays, monday to friday.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTFdG.png)

The graph will look like this. The orders by date.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss08I.png)

Any idea how shall I solve this? Thanks in advance!

I can think of making a calculated column but I'm confused on how to identify my weeks. Shall I create a custom column for Week Number? My Financial year is from oct to sept.

Comment: You may want to look up how to use date tables in Power BI (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/model-date-tables ) Good luck!